# Is there any way to replace Response.Write?

Tags: response.write

My problem is, I have the following function:

```
function change_tarif(param) {
    var arrTarif = <% Response.Write(Session["Tarif"]); %>
    .....
}
```

Session["Tarif"] - contains multidimensional array List and when I'm loading my page it's giving this Error that

The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. `<% ... %>`).

When I delete `<% Response.Write(Session["Tarif"]); %>` it doesn't give this error. So, how can I replace this code to get array List from Session["Tarif"] without using the code blocks `<% %>`?

This is my Array List code in C#:

```
    public void getTarifList()
{
    int intRows = 0;
    string strTarif = "null";
    Session["Tarif"] = "null";

    SqlCommand cmdTarif = new SqlCommand("sp_SIMPay_GetTarifList");
    cmdTarif.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    DataTable dtTarif = SQL.GetData(cmdTarif);

    if (dtTarif.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        intRows = dtTarif.Rows.Count;

        strTarif = "new Array(" + intRows + ");";
        int intIndex = 0;

        foreach (DataRow dRows in dtTarif.Rows)
        {
            strTarif += "arrTarif[" + intIndex + "] = new Array('" + dRows["TarifName"] + "', '" + dRows["ProviderID"] + "', '" + dRows["CodeID"] + "');";
            intIndex++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strTarif = "null";
    }
    Session["Tarif"] = strTarif;
}
```

My full script:

```
function change_tarif(param) {
var  arrTarif = <% Response.Write(Session["Tarif"]); %>
var select = document.getElementById('TarifList');


var i = 0;

if (arrTarif != null) {
    for (i = 0; i < arrTarif.length; i++) {
        if (arrTarif[i][1] == '98' && param == '98') {
            clear_tarif();
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('' + arrTarif[i][0] + '', '' + arrTarif[i][2] + '');
            break;
        }
        else {
            clear_tarif();
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Default Tarif', '');
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Expression` (Equivalent to `Response.Write()`).

```
function change_tarif(param) {
 var arrTarif = <%= Session["Tarif"] %>;
}
```

EDIT : I've customized your code,

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getTarifList();
}
public void getTarifList()
{
    Session["Tarif"] = "null";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("new Array(" + 3 + ");");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("arrTarif[" + i + "] = new Array('A" + i + "', 'B" + i + "', 'C" + i + "');");
    }
    Session["Tarif"] = sb.ToString();
}
```

And markup,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function change_tarif(param){
       var  arrTarif = <% Response.Write(Session["Tarif"]); %>
       return arrTarif;
      }
     console.log(change_tarif('test'));
 </script>
```

Comment: Did you use code blocks <%%> in your container to get the array list?

Comment: AVD, I did what you suggested, but still the same Error. I edited my full script. Maybe something is wrong there?

Comment: Does it throws same error as you've posted? Please add *break* point to verify the result of *stored-proc* and write **console.log** - debug statement to debug JavaScript (open Console Window of Webbrowser).

Comment: Yes, it's throwing the same error as before. I put my js function in a separate file scripts.js and replaced <%Response.Write{Session["Tarif"]);%> with '<%Response.Write{Session["Tarif"]);%>' inside the scripts.js file. It's not giving any Error, but it's also not reading my Array List. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because somewhere in your page code you do something like (just an example - it doesn't matter that it's a `Label` here, any dynamically added/removed control would trigger the error):

```
Label lbl = new Label ();
lbl.Xxxx = ...;

Controls.Add ( lbl ); // this is what triggers your issue
```

When you have `<%= ... %>` in the same container where you also try to dynamically add controls through the use of the `Controls` collection of that container (`Page`, `Panel`, etc.), you'll get that error that you saw.

If you can, try to remove the code that dynamically adds/removes the control to the container (the same container where you have the `<%= ... %>` and then your `<%= ... %>` block will start working.

To remove the dynamic logic that adds/removes control(s), simply put those controls into the container like any other control, like

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lbl" ... />
```

and then simply show/hide the control when you need it. This way the control is always present in the page, you won't have to add/remove it during run-time and then you can have code blocks in the same container.

Here's a quick example that would create this error:

```
...
<div runat="server" id="div1">
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="lbl1" /><br />
    <span>Name:&nbsp;<%= Session["name"] %></span>
</div>
...

// in code-behind
protected override void OnLoad ( EventArgs e )
{
    Label lbl2 = new Label ();
    lbl2.Text = "Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString ();

    // Error: you cannot modify the Controls collection if
    // the same control contains code blocks
    div1.Controls.Add ( lbl2 );
}
```

Comment: But I am not adding any Controls through my code. I'm just creating a new array string in code page and trying to retrieve it in my javascript function.

Comment: @Shohin you'd get the same error if you try to use `Controls.Remove()` as well. You can't change the `Controls` collection in any way of a container that also has code blocks.